# Tipsi-stripe Could not invoke deviceSupportNativePay on android, iOS working fine

Tags: stripe-payments, react-native

### Before I have submitted the issue

[ ] I have read an [installation guide](https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/docs/installation.html)
[ ] I know that for an iOS I need to install pods because I've read the [installation guide](https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/docs/installation.html#cocoapods-ios)
[ ] I have read a [linking guide](https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/docs/linking.html) and checked that everything is OK like in [manual linking guide](https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/docs/linking.html#manual)
[ ] I know that before using `tipsi-stripe` I need to set options for my app as described in [usage guide](https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/docs/usage.html)

### The problem

Error on Android when try to call function deviceSupportNativePay, the error shown as image below

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/54148306/79314833-6cde0680-7f2c-11ea-888d-e1836c038f98.png

Because I'm using RN 0.61.5, first I'm not using manual link, and on iOS is working just fine, not for android though. Now I try manual link for android, but still same issue. Has been followed many issues on stackoverflow and github with no luck. Can confirm stripe object is not null because already initiated it with setOptions.

### Environment

- `tipsi-stripe` version: 7.2.0
- Last `tipsi-stripe` version where the issue was not reproduced (if applicable):
- iOS or Android: Android
- OS version: any version
- React-Native version: 0.61.5
- (Android only) `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` version: 16.0.9
- (Android only) `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base` version: 16.1.0

### Related config

/app/build.gradle

```sh
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "io.fabric"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing,
    bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
    bundleInAlpha: true,
    bundleInBeta: true
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        // debug {
        //     signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        // }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        preDexLibraries = false
        // javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
            // force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
            // force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        } 
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation (project(':tipsi-stripe')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase'
    }
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:27.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    // fbsdk
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'

    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')

    // firebase
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"

    // firebase messaging
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar' // <-- Add this line if you wish to use badge on Android

    // firebase crashlytic
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android/build.gradle

```sh
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 22
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1" 
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion   = 28
    targetSdkVersion    = 28
    buildToolsVersion   = "28.0.3"
    supportLibVersion   = "28.0.0"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
    androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+" 
}
```

MainApplication.java

```java
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

// codepush
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;

// firebase
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.analytics.RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.fabric.crashlytics.RNFirebaseCrashlyticsPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage;

// google sign-in
import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;

import com.gettipsi.stripe.StripeReactPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSBundleFile() {
          return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // firebase
          // packages.add(new RNFirebasePackage());
          packages.add(new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage());
          packages.add(new RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage());
          packages.add(new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage());
          packages.add(new StripeReactPackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    // initializeFlipper(this); // Remove this line if you don't want Flipper enabled
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates.
   *
   * @param context
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(Context context) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.facebook.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass.getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class).invoke(null, context);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

react-native.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'tipsi-stripe': {
      platforms: {
        android: null,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

settings.gradle

```sh
include ':tipsi-stripe'
project(':tipsi-stripe').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/tipsi-stripe/android')
```

Comment: might worth open an issue there https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe

Comment: @wsw actually already open the issue here https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/issues/639, but seems like having slow response, even when I'm trying to reach the community on discord, nobody replied

Comment: i am also facing this issue any body help me